# Setting an environment at a feature level Specflow

Tags: specflow

I have a feature file with 3 scenarios, and i want to know if Specflow has the following implementation: can I set the environment at a feature level? I want to specify the environment at the beginning of the test, so that the scenarios run on the environment specified at the top.

```
Feature: SpecFlowFeature
    In order to avoid silly mistakes
    As a math idiot
    I want to be told the sum of two numbers on DEV environment <= Can I do this? Can DEV be a parameter?

@mytag
Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
    And I have entered 70 into the calculator
    When I press add
    Then the result should be 120 on the screen
```

If i can't do this, can you please provide a solution for my situation? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What do you understand with environment? Dev/Test/Production environment?

Comment: Yes, Dev/Test/Production environment.

Answer (score 0):

My advise would be, use the BeforeFeature hook. This way, you can define your environment there per feature you run.

You can check documentation here. It will solve your problem.
https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks